# Jenkins Batch command Fails

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

```
C:\Users\Natalie\.jenkins\workspace\HW_Class5>Desktop Test  1>>jenkins.txt
```

> "Desktop" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Trying to build a job that creates a file with my name of the desktop.
I am using this command in configure build but it keeps on failing

```
Desktop>echo Natalie>>jenkins.txt
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish ? creating a file in your desktop?

Comment: Your command does exactly what you've asked of it, and the message tells you exactly what is wrong with it. You're trying to run an internal or external command named `desktop` passing it the argument `Test` and redirecting any standard output to a file named `jenkins.txt` in the current working directory, `C:\Users\Natalie\.jenkins\workspace\HW_Class5`.

Comment: Are you supposed to be in the directory of your desktop and launching a command from there? Or are you actually launching a command called desktop?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for, `(Echo(%UserName%)>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\jenkins.txt"`.

Comment: Thanks much! This worked (Echo(%UserName%)>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\jenkins.txt Did not know how to change the directory from within Jenkins Batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that should create a file in Desktop with your username inside you should be:

```bat
>"%userprofile%\Desktop\jenkins.txt" echo %username%
```

This command redirects the output of the command `echo %username%` which prints the value of the `%username%` environment variable (the username of the user currently logged in) to a file in Desktop of the user currently logged in as `%userprofile%` stands for `C:\Users\%username%`.